# Replacing div content in HTML javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

this is still really new to me. I just need to know where I have gone wrong. I want to change the text inside the DIV when the button is clicked. I followed a youtube link (below), because it's been the easiest to follow so far.
However it's still not working.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pyfKqrjmAl4&list=PLKOf7m55-0tHTUAeef0nFy4FNlC6DBnz8

Here is what I have:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>

<div id="book">
<h1>Price</h1>

  <div id="main_section">
      <div id="tablef">
          <div id="table">
              <div id="cell"><h3>Day Time Packages 9am-3pm</h3></div>
          </div>

       <div id="table2">
           <div id="cell2"><h3>Night Time Packages 3pm-Late</h3></div>
       </div>
 </div>
</div>
 <div id="button_section">
 <input type="button"id="my_button" value="Click me"/></div>

</div>

</body>

<script type="text/javascript">
$( document ).ready(function() {

$( "#my_button").click(function() {
    $("main_section").html("this is the updated text"); //the code that changes the content of the div
    });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: You missed `#main_section` in your jQuery selector.

Comment: Thank you. But that still hasn't fixed my problem :(

Answer (score 0):

add hash **#** before **main_section**

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

    $( "#my_button").click(function() {
        $("#main_section").html("this is the updated text"); //the code that changes the content of the div
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#main_section").html("this is the updated text");
```

the selector should be `#main_section` because it is an `ID`, i.e. add `#` before `main_selection`

So your JS code becomes

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

    $( "#my_button").click(function() {
        $("#main_section").html("this is the updated text"); //the code that changes the content of the div
        });
    });
```

Just go through [jQuery Selectors](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_selectors.asp) for better understanding.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {

$( "#my_button").click(function() {
    $("#main_section").html("this is the updated text"); //the code that changes the content of the div
    });
    });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>

<div id="book">
<h1>Price</h1>

  <div id="main_section">
      <div id="tablef">
          <div id="table">
              <div id="cell"><h3>Day Time Packages 9am-3pm</h3></div>
          </div>

       <div id="table2">
           <div id="cell2"><h3>Night Time Packages 3pm-Late</h3></div>
       </div>
 </div>
</div>
 <div id="button_section">
 <input type="button"id="my_button" value="Click me"/></div>

</div>

</body>
```

You just missed # sign in the jquery selector! **($("#main_section"))**